# How to generate Ant and Maven build files for an Eclipse Java project?

Tags: eclipse, maven, ant, build, eclipse-jdt

I have a project which is released like this:

- Export from Eclipse as a jar file.
- Package it with exe4j into an EXE file.

Now I am using some static code analysis tool which requires the project to be built with ant or maven.

It seems both Ant and Maven relies on some build file, so how can I generate it from my Eclipse project?

I tried Eclipse `Export -> Ant Buildfile`, but the exported buildfile seems still relies on **Eclipse built-in builder**.

Maybe I am wrong but my understanding about a builder server should comprise:

- Ant
- JDK
- Source code to be built

Whenever a new source is checked in, Ant can be launched to build the source with JDK. No eclipse should be involved.

I am new to this. Please shed some light.

Comment: You will have to write ant file. Its not something that's auto generated. Its you who specifies where the code is, where to compile that classes from and keep class file to etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution is to export to an Ant buildfile in Eclipse by right-clicking on the project and select **Export --> Ant Buildfiles**.

This would create a buildfile which contains a default target to build the project, in addition to targets which can be used to run your programs. For example, if you already defined run configurations in Eclipse to run a `main` method, a target would be created that allows you to run the program from outside Eclipse. If you have defined a JUnit run configuration to run a certain test, the export would also generate a target to run that test from outside.

Converting to Maven requires more work -- AFAIK there is no official tool or wizard that allows you to generate a full POM configuration from an existing Eclipse project. You can mostly convert to a Maven project by right-clicking on the project and selecting **Configure --> Convert to Maven Project** but this will only generate a POM file and allow choosing the Maven coordinates. Dependencies and plugin configurations need to be added manually.

If you still need to add dependencies into your POM automatically based on the project's `.classpath`, I found [this project](https://github.com/vashishthask/eclipse-to-maven) (haven't tried it though) which seems to do the job.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to convert a project to Maven, you can do right click on the project and follow the picture.

And you get the pom.xml (the configuration file in a Maven project).

And in the pom.xml you have to configure the dependencies you need in the project and the plugins to achieve what to want to do. For example, to create an .exe file with your projects, you could see my answer in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26254232/cannot-recup-dependency-with-maven-assembly-plugin/26255334#26255334)

[image: Maven]

Comment: Thanks for your response. Eclipse already knows the project's dependent files. This information is serialized as the `.classpath` file. After I convert the project to a maven project, it seems the maven managed dependencies are still empty. So do I need to manually add all the dependencies? Why Eclipse `m2e` plugin doesn't do it automatically?

Comment: How could know Eclipse which version of the dependency do you want in your project? That could be one reason. Yes, you have to add the dependencies manually. I encourage you to take a look at maven manual.  Here you have the dependency mechanism --> http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

Comment: Actually I was expecting Eclipse could just fill in the Maven dependencies based on the existing `.classpath` file since that file reflects the project's current dependencies.

Comment: You can not do that. Maven works with external (and local) repos, and you have to follow that way of working. I think that Eclipse and its .classpath file are not enough to fill the pom.xml in Maven. That is why you have to add the dependencies (group/dependency/version) in the pom.xml.

Answer (score 2):

Changing a project to Gradle or Maven (I prefer Gradle, which is like the best of Maven and Ant, combined) is a "big" step (really more of a "medium" step), but probably will serve you well in the long run as a strategic choice. Having said that, if you really want just a tactical option to quickly generate an Ant script, you're on the right track with Eclipse's Export wizard.

**Export** > **Ant Buildfiles** is the starting point, just make sure to *uncheck* the "Create target to compile project using Eclipse compiler" option in that wizard. The generated Ant file should be free of any Eclipse requirements, meaning it should be runnable from a command line without Eclipse.